# Proving that each ear decomposition of a $4$-regular $n$-vertex $2$-connected graph has $n+1$ ears

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

> Prove that in each ear decomposition of a $4$-regular $n$-vertex $2$-connected graph $G$, the number of ears (counting the initial cycle) is $n+1$.

Definition of ear decomposition: $(P_0, P_1, \dots ,P_k)$ of the edge set of G such that (a) $P_0$ is a cycle of length at least 3, and (b) for $i=1,\dots,k$, $P_i$ is an ear of $P_0 \cup P_1 \cup \dots \cup P_i$.

I have started with a proof by induction, and this is what I have so far.

Consider $n=3$. We have a cycle $P_0$ of length 3. From the picture, which is linked below, we can decompose G into $P_0 \cup P_1 \cup P_2 \cup P_3$. Counting the initial cycle, we have 4 ears, which holds for our base case.

Base Case ($n=3$) Graph:

[image]

From here, I am not exactly sure how to articulate my induction step. Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction from here?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question in the case of *simple* graphs and proceed so without induction. (I don't even know if the claim is true otherwise, but from the fact that you consider $n = 3$ as base case, it seems you are considering multigraphs.)

Let $G$ be a (simple) $4$-regular, $2$-connected graph with $n$ vertices. Furthermore, let $P_0, \dots, P_l$ be an ear decomposition of $G$. The claim is equivalent to showing that $l = n$. For that, we use a double counting argument. Namely, let $I = \{(v, k) \in V(G) \times [l] \colon v \text{ is an endpoint of }P_k\}$.

On the one hand, $|I| = 2 l$ as each ear has exactly two (distinct!) endpoints. On the other hand, fix an arbitrary vertex $v \in V(G)$. Let $k$ be the smallest index such that $v \in V(P_0\cup \dots \cup P_k)$. We must have $\deg_{P_0\cup \dots \cup P_k}(v) = 2$: If $k = 0$, then $v$ was initially part of the cycle $P_0$. Otherwise, it must be an internal vertex of $P_k$. Indeed, as $k$ is minimal, $v$ is not a vertex in $P_0\cup \dots \cup P_{k-1}$. In both cases we get $\deg_{P_0\cup \dots \cup P_k}(v) = 2$.

Now, if we add an additional ear, then $v$'s degree can at most increase by one. Indeed, it can only increase if it's precisely the endpoint of that ear. As the endpoints of an ear (in the sense of $2$-vertex-connectedness) are distinct, it must only increase by one.

Hence, as $v$ has degree $4$ in $G$, we must have that $v$ is the endpoint of two ears.

Thus, we get that $|I| = 2 n$. This gives us $n = l$ as desired.